# Closing & reopening mysql connection in after remote API replies

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, database-connection

I am working on a backend application requires some remote API requests, Which take 1~3 second to response depending on load on remote services.

This backend will get ALOT of requests/second, I am trying to achieve best performance I can get out of my server.

Should I close mysql connection before calling the API and reopen it again after receiving the reply to free up some resources ?

If I did so, What wrong may happen?

What I should Do if I can't connect again?

I MUST store and update database after receiving the request.

I am using pure PHP with MySQL (MySQLi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application has to perform some time-consuming task that is not related to the database then you should close the connection so that your PHP process doesn't block the resources on MySQL server.

You can open a new connection after the API call is over. The obvious downside to this is that you will lose the ability to perform transactions. A transaction cannot remain open across two separate MySQL sessions.

An even better option would be to detach the long-running process from your main process. There a number of ways that this can be achieved. If you can run the process in background then it would be the best option. Caching long-running processes is also a viable option. If the user must wait for the whole job to complete then you can employ 2 or 3 step process.

1. User sends a request to the server. Your PHP code does some DB operations and redirects the user to the second step
2. Another PHP process calls the API and does only API related logic. No database connection is established. Once it is done, the application redirects user to the last step.
3. Your PHP application performs another set of DB activities and returns the final response to the user.

Of course, with such complex operations, there is more possibility for your application to lose transactional correctness so you have to evaluate all advantages and disadvantages.

One last point. If your server is set up correctly then your available PHP processes should have a corresponding amount of MySQL processes. This is to ensure that if your PHP processes are utilized at 100% and each one needs to perform some DB operations, then your MySQL server should not be the bottleneck. In this case, **why not make it simple and keep the database connection open while performing the long-running API call? Saves you a lot of trouble.**